# going back to previous state in git

Tags: git, github

So I'm just starting to learn git and I'm completely new to command line so struggling a bit.

So far I've learnt the simple things. Initializing, staging changes and then committing changes. Then I pushed all my changes to GitHub.

Now what I want to learn is going back to previous commits in git. So my test project currently has two commits and I want to go from 2 to 1. This is what I used to do that

git revert "my hash here"

This is what git returned:

```
$ git revert a7da914393d0400f9a4eb77fd263e125a8ce7c57
error: 'revert' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree,
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,
hint: or use 'git commit -a'.
fatal: revert failed
```

Just wondering what this means and why it failed???

Comment: Did you *read* the message, and follow the hints?

Comment: @poke well I'm currently trying to work out what they mean, that's why I posted it on here and of course I'm currently going through some tutorials to try and work out the answer.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922747/understanding-commits-in-git/31923288#31923288)

Comment: first clean your local working copy.  

`git checkout .`

Answer (score 1):

Going back to previous commit is not reverting - what you want is resetting.
Try

```
git reset <your hash here>
```

And read also the documentation about revert and reset:
[git revert tutorial](https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert)

Comment: I got the command I used of a tutorial that said it would work. Would it be possible for you to explain to me what is means by unmerged files

Comment: If you are trying to completely reset back to a previous commit and you *don't care about outstanding changes* and you are *willing to delete those changes without any chance of recovery* then you can use `git reset --hard <hash>` to rollback your working copy to a previous commit.

Answer (score 0):

save unmerged files in stash, before revert.

```
git stash save

git revert a7da914393d0400f9a4eb77fd263e125a8ce7c57

git stash pop
```

unmerged files. maybe they are files in which unresolved conflicts occured while merging